# Why does this parse as a date?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript:

```
new Date('SE-1572')
```

And this parses as

```
Sat Jan 01 1572 00:00:00 GMT-0001 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Clearly the javascript engine v8 is picking up the 1572 in the string and parsing this as a date but the SE- part should cause the engine to not parse the date correctly.

Interestingly this

```
new Date('SE1572')
```

Does not parse correctly.

Comment: Works in Chrome but doesn't in Firefox, you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Everything new Date() takes is optional other than year and month. Clearly both are wrong but because of the "-" in your first example it is parsing the letters a month and the numbers as a year. Dates are zero based and basically any non month string evaluates to 0 or January. Try 'null-1992' or litterally 'anything-2009'

Comment: @DougF actually dates are zero based so SZ doesn't match any month string so it evals to false which === 0 which is January.

Comment: @GifCo If this is not a dupe, remove your comments and write them as a proper answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado what the hell are you talking about?

Comment: @GifCo I meant: *"if this question is not a duplicate of an existing question already answered, please consider deleting your comments and writing a proper answer, that way contributing for S.O."* That was just a friendly advice, I reckon that your comment was spot on and I was willing to upvoting an eventual answer of yours. Not anymore. Have a nice day.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I thought you were trying to say i was BS'ing lol. Not only am i not going to look for a duplicate answer Im also not going to write an answer, no offence to the OP but this is kind of a pointless question and not much search-ability anyway.

Comment: Looks like relevant code is here: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/dateparser-inl.h - "The first number has to be separated from garbage words by whitespace or other separators."

Comment: @GifCo So it just tries it's best to find a date in a string that seems entirely invalid.

Comment: @Dave3of5 its actually more valid than it seems. For example Date('dec-1572') is perfectly valid (Date on requires month and year). IM not 100% sure but it looks like Chrome returns false for any unrecognized month which coerces to 0 which is January. According to MDN SpiderMonkey (aka Firefox) will return "Invalid Date" instead of this weird behavior. Gotta love JS!!!

Comment: @GifCo Ah crap thanks for the answer looks like I'll need to parse the dates then with an external lib thanks for the response !